# Javascript not running with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, web, web-deployment

I have a comics website which loops through all images in a db and displays them as thumbnails. The user can click on one of those images to see it in normal size on a viewcomic.php template.

I'd like to allow users to press left and right arrows to navigate images.

In viewcomic.php, I have the following javascript which only runs when I comment out any php.

```
     //so if I comment out this line, it will run fine 
var imgArray = [<?php echo implode(',', getImages()) ?>];

$(document).ready(function() {
    var img = document.getElementById("theImage");
    alert("run");
    var imgIndex = 0;
    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 39) {
            alert("next image");
            img.src = imgArray[imgIndex++]
        }

    });
});
```

In firebug, I'm getting the following error:

```
invalid regular expression flag a
[Break On This Error]
```

Referring to:

```
 var imgArray = [/images/all_comics/'Number_1.jpg',/images/all_comics/'Number_2.j...
```

But, Firebug shows that imgArray seems to be properly filled with jscript-readable strings:

```
 var imgArray = [/images/all_comics/'Number_1.jpg',/images/all_comics/'Number_2.jpg',/images/all_comics/'Number_3.jpg',/images/all_comics/'Number_4.jpg',/images/all_comics/'Number_5.jpg'];
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Try to quote your array values.

Comment: @budwiser They are quoted. This is the output from firebug:
var imgArray = [/images/all_comics/'Number_1.jpg',...

Comment: They are quoted wrong, the quotes need to go around the complete path, not just around the filename: `'/images/all_comics/Number_1.jpg'`

Comment: You need to quote the wholething - `var imgArray = ['/images/all_comics/Number_1.jpg','/images/all_comics/Number_2.jpg', ... ];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Firebug error states, because your array values are quoted incompletely, it parses them as faulty regular expressions because of the slashes which are regexp delimiters.

Instead of

`/images/all_comics/'Number_1.jpg'`

you need to quote the whole value as

`'/images/all_comics/Number_1.jpg'`

Answer (score 1):

you need to add quotes to your strings, for example like that:

```
var imgArray = ['<?php echo implode("','", getImages()) ?>'];
```

another possibility would be to use json:

```
var imgArray = <?php echo json_encode(getImages())?>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var imgArray = [<?php echo implode(',', getImages()) ?>];
```

to

```
var imgArray = ["<?php echo implode('","', getImages()) ?>"];
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getImages()` function seems to try and quote the strings, but it quotes only the filename, not the complete path:

```
/images/all_comics/'Number_1.jpg'
```

vs.

```
'/images/all_comics/Number_1.jpg'
```

which leads to a incorrect syntax in the `[]` declaration.